# How to read real time ECG data in Samsung Galaxy Watch 4 - Wear OS?

Tags: wear-os, google-contacts-api, samsung-galaxy-watch-4

I'm trying to access **Samsung Galaxy Watch 4** real time **ECG** (eletrocardiogram) values using SensorManager and SensorEventListener in Android Studio. I tried to access it by sensor constant number (type_number) which references **com.samsung.sensor.ecg** and nothing was returned by this sensor. How can i access this ECG data via Android Studio?

Comment: Did you figure out what the ECG data?

Comment: I'm also interesting in this (and any other Wear Sensors which we can register but they not providing any data). Please inform me if you figure out something!